# How to I get the real value from Dynamics 365 instead of GUID?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, dynamics-crm, azure-data-factory, microsoft-dynamics

I am using Azure Data Factory (ADF) to load data from Dynamics 365 to an Azure Database. However, for some columns I get a GUID value like `8234CCBA-7B01-E211-B551-D48564518CCA` instead of the actual value.

Is there a way to retrieve the real data either by using SQL or changing something in Dynamics?

Comment: You want to get field value, but got the record guid instead?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly that.

Comment: Can you provide the code which you use to retrieve the field value?

Comment: I use Data Factory's Copy Activity and load data directly from Dynamics to my Azure DB

Comment: @adnane you have to load other Foreign Key (GUID) housing tables as well.. then you can INNER JOIN to get the fields like Name and other related fields

Comment: @ArunVinoth I have never worked with Dynamics before, can you please tell me where I can find these housing tables ?

Comment: @adnane lets say, you are pulling Contact into Azure DB using ADF. Contact has ParentCustomer as Account GUID. In that case, you have to pull Account table also into Azure DB using ADF.. so the relationships are intact.. make sense?

Comment: @ArunVinoth Yes it makes sense. But how do I know if ParentCustomer belongs to Account ?

Comment: @adnane that can be checked in your Dynamics Org schema (Data model) entity relationships..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally we will use web api formatted values or CRM SDK methods to get the display name field of related table (Foreign key) in C# or javascript. In ADF, I don't think you can fetch the formatted values for picklist (Integer key values) or lookup (GUID) attributes.

Instead you can use ADF data flow to fetch the different datasets and join them for these kind of data transformations. [Read more](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5992/configuring-azure-data-factory-data-flow/)

[image]

Otherwise, dump all the datasets you need into Azure DB - for transformations later in DB views.

Comment: There is a possibility in ADF to create a Web activity or use an Azure function. Can you please share the code used to do get that display name ?